# Ansible sudo_user issue with command module

Tags: ansible

I have a working task e.g:

```
  - hosts: webservers
    sudo: yes    
    gather_facts: yes    
    tasks:
        - name: Create temp directory
          file: state=directory path="{{ debian.tmp_dir }}"
        - name: Correct Apt Dependency
          command: apt-get -f install -y
```

but when I added `sudo_user: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"`, it requires me to modify command to work properly by adding sudo prefix to command e.g

```
- hosts: webservers
    sudo: yes
    sudo_user: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"
    gather_facts: yes    
    tasks:
        - name: Create temp directory
          file: state=directory path="{{ debian.tmp_dir }}"
        - name: Correct Apt Dependency
          command: sudo apt-get -f install -y
```

Given the ansible_ssh_user in sudoers list why we need to add sudo in later case when `sudo_user` is other than `root` ?

The actual issue I want to get around is  creation of tmp directory , it should be `ubuntu:ubuntu` if `ansible_ssh_user` is `ubuntu` , without adding `user=ubuntu, group=ubuntu`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably run `play` as regular user and explicitly specify commands that require root privileges use `sudo: yes` per task. In this case directory will be created as regular user ( Task 2 ):

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all

  vars:

    debian_tmp_dir: /tmp/my_temp_dir

  tasks:

    - name: Create temp directory
      file: state=directory path={{ debian_tmp_dir }}

    - name: Create root file
      sudo: yes
      command: touch /tmp/root_temp_file

    - name: Check debian_tmp_dir file permissions
      stat: path={{ debian_tmp_dir }}
      register: user_folder_permissions

    - name: Check file created with sudo permissions
      stat: path=/tmp/root_temp_file
      register: root_file_permissions

    - debug: var=user_folder_permissions.stat.pw_name

    - debug: var=root_file_permissions.stat.pw_name
```

Output:

```
==> default: Running provisioner: ansible...

PLAY [all] ********************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [default]

TASK: [Create temp directory] *************************************************
ok: [default]

TASK: [Create root file] ******************************************************
changed: [default]

TASK: [Check {{ debian_tmp_dir }} file permissions] ***************************
ok: [default]

TASK: [Check file created with sudo permissions] ******************************
ok: [default]

TASK: [debug var=user_folder_permissions.stat.pw_name] ************************
ok: [default] => {
    "var": {
        "user_folder_permissions.stat.pw_name": "vagrant"
    }
}

TASK: [debug var=root_file_permissions.stat.pw_name] **************************
ok: [default] => {
    "var": {
        "root_file_permissions.stat.pw_name": "root"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
default                    : ok=7    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: I required sudo on most of the tasks so , adding sudo to each is just overdone. My issue resolved simply by : `sudo: yes` with `user: ubuntu `